# Assalamualaikum; is it haram if I join a racing circuit where you pay money to get taught by an instructor and join competitions

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

I need to know if it's ok to practice in such a place and if it's ok to pay money to be taught there and to join the competitions where if you win you get a trophy??

Answer (score 1):

Walekum salaam wa rahmatullahi sister,

There is nothing in Islam which explicitly prohibits such activity. However, one needs to make sure that it does violate any of the general guidelines of Islam. Like-

1. It should not involve free-mixing of men and women, and unnecessary interaction with non-mehrams.
2. It should not involve dressing in a way that is against the guidelines of modesty in Islam.
3. It should not prevent one from the remembrance and worship of Allaah. I'll put some emphasis on this point. It is usually seen that people who are active in sports end up giving too much time to it such that they even miss to pray on time. It is not worth it sister. One might get a trophy in this world in such sports but the trophy (of Jannah) that one will get in sha Allaah in hereafter is far far greater. One must not lose the focus of trophy of hereafter while working for a trophy in this world.
4. Also, it is recommended for women to stay at home unless they really need to go out for some work. (in fact, it not recommended for men either to unnecessarily roam here and there).

And Allaah knows the best.